# Most efficient option for build 3D structures using Eigen matrices

Tags: c++, pointers, matrix, eigen

I need a 3D matrix/array structure on my code, and right now I'm relying on Eigen for both my matrices and vectors.

Right now I am creating a 3D structure using `new`:

```
MatrixXd* cube= new MatrixXd[60];
for (int i; i<60; i++) cube[i]=MatrixXd(60,60);
```

and for acessing the values:

```
double val;
MatrixXd pos;
for (int i; i<60; i++){
    pos=cube[i];
    for (int j; j<60; j++){
        for (int k; k<60; k++){
            val=pos(j,k);
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

However, right now it is very slow in this part of the code, which makes me beleive that this might not be the most efficient way. Are there any alternatives?

Comment: If you really need a 3D matrix then there isn't a way around using that nested loop.  With a 60x60x60 matrix you've got 216,000 values that you're keeping, so it's always going to be relatively slow.  What problem are you trying to solve?  Maybe there is a way to solve it without a 3D matrix.

Comment: I'm calculating a NxN matrix for a certain number of time steps, and I need to store the data for each instant so that I can perform a weighted average at the end. My question was more about the use of `new` - more precisely, if there aren't any other types of array (maybe in boost libraries) that can be used to stack several MatrixXd.

Answer (score 6):

While it was not available, when the question was asked, Eigen has been providing a Tensor module for a while now. It is still in an "unsupported" stage (meaning the API may change), but basic functionality should be mostly stable. The documentation is scattered [here](https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/src/0788c45d52fd93b0832af14b455b1bbef3914698/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/src/Tensor/README.md?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default) and [here](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/unsupported/group__CXX11__Tensor__Module.html).

Answer (score 3):

An alternative is to create a very large chunk of memory ones, and maps Eigen matrices from it:

```
double* data = new double(60*60 * 60*60*60);

Map<MatrixXd> Mijk(data+60*(60*(60*k)+j)+i), 60, 60);
```

At this stage you can use Mijk like a MatrixXd object. However, since this not a MatrixXd type, if you want to pass it to a function, your function must either:

- be of the form `foo(Map<MatrixXd> mat)`
- be a template function: `template<typename Der> void foo(const MatrixBase<Der>& mat)`
- take a `Ref<MatrixXd>` object which can handle both `Map<>` and `Matrix<>` objects without being a template function and without copies. ([doc](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/classEigen_1_1Ref.html))

Answer (score 3):

A solution I used is to form a fat matrix containing all the matrices you need stacked.

```
MatrixXd A(60*60,60);
```

and then access them with [block operations](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialBlockOperations.html)

```
A0 = A.block<60,60>(0*60,0);
...
A5 = A.block<60,60>(5*60,0);
```

Comment: Why in these examples do ones use examples with equally spaced dimensions?! Why not 30x40x50?!