# Eigen::Tensor, how to access matrix from Tensor

Tags: c++, eigen3, tensor

I have the following Eigen Tensor:

```
Eigen::Tensor<float, 3> m(3,10,10);
```

I want to access the 1st matrix. In numpy I would do it as such

```
m(0,:,:)
```

How would I do this in Eigen

Comment: I usually don't work with tensors in eigen, but here is some documentation I found that may help: https://github.com/RLovelett/eigen/tree/master/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/src/Tensor. There is also a workaround here for using matrices instead of tensors when dimensions are > 2: https://studywolf.wordpress.com/2012/09/16/n-dimensional-matrices-in-c/. Good luck

Comment: I looked through the entire doc. There isn't any reference on how to access a block /matrix of a 3d tensor

Comment: You may have to create your own unique solution like the other stackoverflow post...here are some other workarounds using the MatrixXd type: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17098218/most-efficient-option-for-build-3d-structures-using-eigen-matrices.

Comment: By the way, if you like numpy, then check out xtensor library for c++ if you have time. The api is very similar to numpy and you can access multidimensional arrays similar to numpy.

Comment: is this library fast?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can access parts of a tensor using `.slice(...)` or `.chip(...)`. Do this to access the first matrix, equivalent to numpy `m(0,:,:)`:

```cxx
Eigen::Tensor<double,3> m(3,10,10);          //Initialize
m.setRandom();                               //Set random values 
std::array<long,3> offset = {0,0,0};         //Starting point
std::array<long,3> extent = {1,10,10};       //Finish point
std::array<long,2> shape2 = {10,10};         //Shape of desired rank-2 tensor (matrix)
std::cout <<  m.slice(offset, extent).reshape(shape2) << std::endl;  //Extract slice and reshape it into a 10x10 matrix.
```

If you want the "second" matrix, you use `offset={1,0,0}` instead, and so on.

You can find [the most recent documentation here](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/unsupported/eigen_tensors.html).

Comment: While it does print, ```m.slice(offset, extent).reshape(shape2)``` does not return an Eigen Matrix type.

Comment: @MadeleineP.Vincent You are correct, this returns an expression of type `Eigen::TensorReshapingOp`. [See this post on how to convert back to Eigen::Matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48795789/eigen-unsupported-tensor-to-eigen-matrix)

Comment: @DavidAce is it possible to extract a slice and reshape it into a 3-by-10 matrix instead? I am struggling to extract a non-square matrix. This in MATLAB would be equivalent to ``val(:,:,1) ``

Comment: @Jamie Yes! For a slice along the third axis in this example, you should take `offset = {0,0,0}`, `extent = {3,10,1}`, and then `shape2 = {3,10}`.